# excel- purchase cost function with multiple variables

Tags: excel, function

So I'm not good with excel (computers in general) and can do some things but this one is out of my league.
**This is the problem:**

The cost of a used car is highly correlated with the following variables:

```
 t= age of car              1 ≤ t ≤ 5 (years)
 V= volume of engine        1000 ≤ V ≤ 2500 (cubic centimeters)
 D= number of doors         D= 2,3,4,5
 A= accessories and style   A= 1,2,3,4,5,6 (qualitative)
```

Using regression analysis, the following relationship between the cost and four independent variables was found:

```
purchase cost= (1+1/t)*V*(D/2+A)
```

Plot the purchase price of the car as a function of the four variables.

I know how to input the function into excel and only use one number from each variable:

```
Function:
=(1+(1/B2))*C2*((D2/2)+E2
Where: B2=1, C2=1000, D2=2, E2=1
Which: A1=4000 (for the purchase cost)
```

What I don't know is how to make the function use multiple number combinations within those variables (i.e. how to change one variable and not the others). I've looked up "youtube" videos and numerous websites to figure this out and none of them showed me what I needed to know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have fundamentally solved your problem but there is a typo in your formula which is preventing it from calculating. Add a closing parenthesis at the end your formula.  Then assuming that the formula is placed in cell A1 and your example values are placed in the cells indicated in your post, simply type a new numeric value in B2, C2, D2 and/or E2 'manually' and your formula result will update.

If you wish you can create a dropdown list in your cells to hold the list of values for each of your variables.  [This link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-drop-down-list-HA102809802.aspx) should get you going.

Comment: How would you suggest plotting this? The Dropbox works great but when I plot it, the y-axis is the purchase cost in column A-- which works fine--but the x-axis turned into numbers 1-5, which is representing columns A-E. What do you think I should use for an x-axis?